Interpretation of Seagate SMART attributes
I have a Seagate Barracuda SATA HDD. I have run both a short and long test using SMARTCTL. Both failed with 90% remaining.
I then looked at the SMART attributes for this HDD. They are listed in the link below.
Questions I have:

Is there anything in the SMART attributes that may indicate the HDD is going to fail?
Looking at the raw values, it looks to me like nothing has exceeded threshold values (some have to be below the threshold and some above to create cause for concern)? Is this correct?
Just because the short and long tests failed, doesn't necessarily mean the HDD will fail? This means a bad sector was found and the test was halted?

The drive has run for 13574 hours and runs 24/7.
Link

“Just because the short and long tests failed, doesn't necessarily mean the HDD will fail?” - My Magic Eightball answered with “all signs point towards no”, but seriously, the built-in test suggests your drive is failing, are there any other signs? Your running those tests for some reason

Thanks for the reply. The HDD runs in a desktop PC which is running Ubuntu server. It is my home server that runs 24/7. There are no obvious signs that the HDD will fail, I just thought it'd be a good idea to check its health. I have it all backed up, but I don't really want to wait until a failure to replace it. Then again, I don't want to spend money unnecessarily if I don't have to.
